# Javascript [defer] attribute and document.ready?

Tags: javascript, jquery, deferred

After reading about the `defer` attribute at [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/script)

> This Boolean attribute is set to indicate to a browser that the script
>   is meant to be executed after the document has been parsed.

It looks nice.

So I've [tested](http://jsbin.com/ujatif/3/edit) it against  `$(function () { });`  and  `$(window).load(...)`

```
<script>
$(function ()
{
  alert('1')
});
$(window).load(function ()
{
  alert('2')
});
</script>

<script defer="defer">
  alert('4');
</script>
```

This code *Always* output `4,1,2` !

Ok So now I can recognize the time where the document is parsed.

In what scenarious will i need the stage *before* document.ready  (where the parse time complete) ?

Comment: An important caveat: `"Since this feature hasn't yet been implemented by all other major browsers, authors should not assume that the script’s execution will actually be deferred."`

Comment: @jbabey yah I know. but please notice - it **IS** gonna be implemented in all major brwser. so it is worth learning about its behaviour :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/script)

> The defer attribute shouldn't be used on scripts that don't have the
>   src attribute

The actual use would be that you can still have scripts at the top of the page and make the browser load them after the entire page is parsed fully thus improving the client side of the performance.

From [YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom)

> The DEFER attribute indicates that the script does not contain
>   document.write, and is a clue to browsers that they can continue
>   rendering

Comment: so why not putting them at the bottom ? what is the difference ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir, for some templating systems/CMSs the person writing the JavaScript doesn't have access to the HTML template. Additionally, it simplifies organization of meta-data if much of it is left in the `<head>` and `<body>` is strictly content.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [W3 HTML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-script-element.html#attr-script-defer):

> The async and defer attributes are boolean attributes that indicate how the script should be executed. The defer and async attributes must not be specified if the src attribute is not present.

So, this attribute is only valid for *external* scripts.

Comment: yeah . good point. I could reference a js file which include the alert command. it was just for sample. and of-course you right !

Comment: Yes, you should do that to really test the behavior